# C# Switching Through Panels by Button Click

Tags: c#, panels

I am having Trouble switching through panels that is already inside the panels. I'm trying to make a Windows form with Switchable tabs, and i want the panels to switch depending on what buttons the user clicks. I tried to code it like this

```
private void Dashboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnl_dashboard.Visible = true;
    pnl_purchase_sales.Visible = false;
    pnl_order_stocks.Visible = false;
    pnl_inventory_forecasting.Visible = false;
    pnl_stocks.Visible = false;
    pnl_alert_logs.Visible = false;
    pnl_accounting_tools.Visible = false;
}

private void Purchase_sales_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnl_purchase_sales.Visible = true;
    pnl_purchase_sales.BringToFront();
    pnl_order_stocks.Visible = false;
    pnl_inventory_forecasting.Visible = false;
    pnl_stocks.Visible = false;
    pnl_alert_logs.Visible = false;
    pnl_accounting_tools.Visible = false;
}

private void stocks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnl_stocks.Visible = true;
    pnl_stocks.BringToFront();
    pnl_purchase_sales.Visible = false;
    pnl_order_stocks.Visible = false;
    pnl_inventory_forecasting.Visible = false;
    pnl_alert_logs.Visible = false;
    pnl_accounting_tools.Visible = false;
}

private void order_stocks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnl_order_stocks.Visible = true;
    pnl_order_stocks.BringToFront();
    pnl_purchase_sales.Visible = false;
    pnl_inventory_forecasting.Visible = false;
    pnl_stocks.Visible = false;
    pnl_alert_logs.Visible = false;
    pnl_accounting_tools.Visible = false;
}

private void inventory_forecasting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnl_inventory_forecasting.Visible = true;
    pnl_inventory_forecasting.BringToFront();
    pnl_purchase_sales.Visible = false;
    pnl_order_stocks.Visible = false;
    pnl_stocks.Visible = false;
    pnl_alert_logs.Visible = false;
    pnl_accounting_tools.Visible = false;
}

private void alert_logs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnl_alert_logs.Visible = true;
    pnl_alert_logs.BringToFront();
    pnl_purchase_sales.Visible = false;
    pnl_order_stocks.Visible = false;
    pnl_inventory_forecasting.Visible = false;
    pnl_stocks.Visible = false;
    pnl_accounting_tools.Visible = false;
}

private void accounting_tools_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnl_accounting_tools.Visible = true;
    pnl_accounting_tools.BringToFront();
    pnl_purchase_sales.Visible = false;
    pnl_order_stocks.Visible = false;
    pnl_inventory_forecasting.Visible = false;
    pnl_stocks.Visible = false;
    pnl_alert_logs.Visible = false;
}
```

It works when you start from the main panel going down but it wont work when you just randomly click a panel. Here's my Form

[image]

Comment: Do you need to set `pnl_dashboard.Visible = true;` in all the click event handlers?

Comment: you should rethink your approach .. your code is not really maintainable and  the more panels you add the messier it will become .. kick this over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for help with taking a better approach

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing more code, but could it be because `pnl_dashboard.Visible` is never set to false?

Comment: Well that's pretty much all the codes needed to run the panel switching. And no. The reason why pnl_dashboard.Visible does not exist on the rest of the Button_click except for itself, because the other existing panels exist inside that panel so if i set it to false theres no panel that will show up. The default value of pnl_dashboard was set to visible.

Comment: @RavenPotterskin so you made the dashboard panel as a referenced panel, then you need to set it true on  form load, because if you click on Dashboard, then go to the rest, it'll work probably, but if you click on any button other than Dashboard, it won't work, because the dashboard 
 has not set to visible.